# Bringing shrink-wrapped cheese through Australian Customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, australia

I have purchased cheese in France and it is shrink wrapped. Do I have to declare the cheese to customs or not?

Comment: I believe all food products have to be declared on the landing card.

Answer (score 10):

The question on the [landing card](http://www.immi.gov.au/About/Documents/managing-australias-borders/english-ipc-sample.pdf) is:

> Are you bringing into Australia:
>
> […]
>
> 6. Meat, poultry, fish, seafood, eggs, dairy, fruit, vegetables?

This is pretty broad and definitely includes cheese. Also, as the card implies, you should always check “yes” and/or seek advice from customs officials if you are unsure (that's true everywhere). At the end of the day, I suspect cheese (unlike vegetables or meat) should be OK but failing to declare it could bring further trouble if it isn't.

Whether you are allowed to keep it might however depend on the type of cheese (from raw or pasteurised milk, shelf-stable or refrigerated), maybe someone else will be able to provide more details on that.

Answer (score 7):

As others have mentioned, you will certainly need to declare it.

France is on the Department of Agriculture FMD approved country list, which means the cheese should be OK to bring in, as long as it is less than 10kg, commercially prepared and packaged and intended for human consumption. [Source](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/travelling/cant-bring-form/australian_biosecurity)

From the information I could find, the only sticking point might be how well your cheese is wrapped.